# Class design: list of 'habits' in Habit-class, or distinct class?

Tags: php, oop, class

I have a question related to the design of classes. I think I understand the theory behind object-oriented programming and design, but I am having a difficult time practicing this on my web-app.

Let's assume I have this web-app where I am tracking my habits. I have database-tables called 'habits', 'events' and 'goals'. I think I will make a class called 'Habit', that sounds pretty logical in my opinion.
So far so good. But I also have the homescreen of the app where I want to display a list of all my habits (each habit has a name that is displayed, but I also need to show just a little info from the 'events'-table per habit).
Now comes my question: this list of habits, is that a distinct class? Or a method of the general 'Habit'-class? What's good practice? On what kind of things does this depend? What kind of aspects do I have to consider while making these decisions?

Comment: You'd do well to look into [Object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (ORM). There are plenty of PHP packages to help you achieve it, too, such as [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) and [Propel](http://propelorm.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Habit` class should represent a singular, distinct habit; it should not know how to generate a collection of other `Habit` objects. PeteH has a pretty good answer, except that [Java-like generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) is not supported in PHP.

What I would do in this situation is likely have a `HabitModel` that provides a method to retrieve a specific `Habit` object by an identifier and a method that provides a collection of `Habit` objects. Most commonly in PHP you'll see this collection returned as an array.

```
<?php

class HabitModel {

    public function getHabitById($id) {
        $data = $this->db->query($habitSql); // assuming this will be something that returns data associated to $habit_id
        return new Habit($data);
    }

    public function getAllHabits() {
        $allData = $this->db->query($allHabitSql);
        $habits = array();
        foreach ($allData as $data)
        {
            $habits[] = new Habit($data);
        }

        return $habits;
    }

}
```

---

I would suggest that thinking about how to design this properly you should strive to adhere to the Single Responsibility Principle. A class should be responsible for doing a singular thing. In this case the `Habit` object is responsible for representing the data associated to a `Habit`; it is not responsible for gathering the data or handling the structure of multiple `Habit` objects. Organizing the `Habit` objects into the appropriate data structure is a responsibility for another part of the system.

Comment: yes that looks good. Both this answer and mine see a class which sits separately to Habit and maintains some kind of array/collection/list. And that's as it should be, this type of question is pure design and the basic approach should be good across all languages, although as we can see the implementations may be slightly different.

Comment: @cspray I see you call the class 'HabitModel'. Does that have anything to do with the MVC-pattern?

With your last sentence "Organizing the Habit objects into the appropriate data structure is a responsibility for another part of the system", do you aim at yet another class in (probably) the Controller-part of the system? Or does that sentence relate to the getAllHabits()-function?

Comment: @Abe1984 Yes, typically I design my own personal projects in a "MVC like" architecture I think is more suitable for the web then your traditional "desktop MVC". However, if you're working with a legacy system you can have this still named as a model or you could name it something else and give it fewer responsibilities. Some legacy systems that I've worked in I have added a class named 'Gatherer' that just fetches the appropriate data. The best name for this component is really gonna be up to your existing architecture.

Comment: @cspray Awesome, thanks a lot. Class design and MVC make more sense now. I am left with one question though: What exactly do you mean with the last sentence from your original answer? Are you making the distinction between 'habit' and 'habitlist' there again? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Abe1984 Yes, exactly. Distinguishing between a single `Habit` entity and a collection of multiple `Habit` objects or `HabitList`

Answer (score 2):

No, the "list of habits" sits over and above the Habit class.

I don't know php, but for example in c# you might have:

```
class Habits : List<Habit>
{
   ....
}
```

which will allow you to add functionality at the "habits" level, or even more straightforward you could just have

```
List<Habit>
```

if no functionality is required at the Habits level.

But Habit and Habits are definitely distinct from each other.